# How do you pass information to and from a non activity class?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-context

So I have this "middle man" nonactivity class, where I want to get a string path from an activity class. Then, from my nonactivity class send that string path to a different activity?

Activity A

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     Intent imageToFactory = new Intent(this,NonActivity.class);
     imageToFactory.putExtra("yourImage", user_image_path);//I already set user_image path
}
```

NonActivity

```
public class NonActivity

{
    private Intent grabImagePath = new Intent();
    private String grabImagePathString = getIntent.getStringExtra("yourImage");//this obviously gives an error but for the example

    public String grabUserImage()
    {
        return grabImagePathString;
    }
}
```

Activity B

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     NonActivity nonActivity;
     String example = nonActivity.grabUserImage();
}
```

So this method doesn't work for some reason, I think I have to use contexts some how but im not sure exactly how to use them, if anyone can help with examples or modify the example code i did below that'd be awesome!

Comment: Why not just pass the string path from one activity to another through the intent when calling the second activity?

Comment: Well, because I want the Nonactivity to be a storage/server kind of class, there are multiple reasons why I'm doing it this way.

Comment: you can pass data from activty to another activtity only with sharedpreference,static, application

Answer (score 1):

You can build a static variable that can serve as message bridge, first thing you need to create a class and name it anything you like, in my case I will name the example class as Conn, then add a static HashMap.

```
public class Conn {

    public static HashMap<String,String> storage = new HashMap<>();

}
```

To utilize this this class in your example:

Activity A

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    Conn.storage.put("yourImage",user_image_path_in_string);

}
```

Activity B

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

     String example = Conn.storage.get("yourImage");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use third class ( here NonActivity.class ) for some reasons, just do it like this:

create globals class like this :

package helper;

```
public class Globals {

private static final Globals instance = new Globals();
private GlobalVariables globalVariables = new GlobalVariables();

private Globals() {
}

public static Globals getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public GlobalVariables getValue() {
    return globalVariables;
}

}
```

and global variables class like this :

```
public class GlobalVariables {
public String grabImagePathString;
}
```

now in activity A::

```
Globals.getInstance().getValue(). grabImagePathString = "something......";
```

and in activity B::

```
String gtabImagePathString = Globals.getInstance().getValue(). grabImagePathString;
```

Good Luck

Comment: So gtabImagePathString is reading as null in Activity B, for some reason it can't get the string path?!?